# minimization: how to do efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

how to do this minimization(given in image) in python,numpy efficiently
I have matrix of dimension `1600 * 900` 
And want to calculate best Possible U and V

[minimize this in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDJMN.png)

Comment: have you considered defining the items or at least their data type in the formula contained in the image?

Comment: The description is incomplete (as norok mentioned) and this optimization is not trivial! Either there is an algorithm presented in that paper of yours describing this problem or you need to create own using some non-trivial theory. Hint: it can be interpreted as sum of a smooth function and a convex separable function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Scipy's minimize function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), which may help you?